# smtp working pop not working

Tags: email, email-bounces

My DNS settings are as follows.

A Record:

HOST = @ POINTS TO = 65.75.241.26

HOST = beta POINTS TO =  65.75.241.26

HOST = stable POINTS TO 65.75.241.26

CNAME Records:

HOST = e POINTS TO email.softmail.me

HOST = email POINTS TO email.softmail.me

HOST = imap POINTS TO imap.softmail.me

HOST = mail POINTS TO pop.softmail.me

HOST = pop POINTS TO pop.softmail.me

HOST = smtp POINTS TO smtp.softmail.me

MX records

PRIORITY = 5 HOST = @ POINTS TO = smtp.softmail.me

Please verify whether the above settings are correct or not that I cannot receive any email to my mail server.

In my code I used settings as

Mail outgoing : smtp.softmail.me port 25

Mail incoming : pop.softmail.me port 110

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't look like you've made the correct entries in your godaddy dns settings.
There doesn't seem to be an ip address associated with smtp.softmail.me or imap.softmail.me

dig @ns70.domaincontrol.com imap.softmail.me +short
imap.softmail.me.

dig @ns70.domaincontrol.com pop.softmail.me +short
pop.softmail.me.

You have a CNAME pointing to itself.

You'll want to setup A Records for pop.softmail.me and imap.softmail.me and make sure those are resolving correctly by issuing the command above.

Comment: dig @ns70.domaincontrol.com imap.softmail.me +short imap.softmail.me.

dig @ns70.domaincontrol.com pop.softmail.me +short pop.softmail.me. I am not clear with the above 2 lines what are they? What do they refer for?

Comment: Do I need to create A records only for pop and imap pointing to my IP? Doesn't I need to create an A record for smtp?